# How to add the Chi-square effect size Cramer's V in the summary table using R package “gtsummary”?

Tags: r, gtsummary

## Question

I am working with a gtsummary table that includes statistical tests for both means and frequencies. I want to include effect sizes to the table and came across [this post which shows how to do it for Wilcox test effect size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67262846/how-to-add-the-effect-size-in-the-summary-table-using-r-package-gtsummary). The code also works for Cohen's d, but I am struggling to modify it for Cramer's V. It seems the cramer_v() function needs to call a ready-made contingency table, rather than working with raw data. Is there any way to calculate and include Cramer's V for the chi-square in the gtsummary table?

## Example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(gtsummary)
theme_gtsummary_mean_sd()

my_ES_test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  rstatix::cohens_d(data, as.formula(glue::glue("{variable} ~ {by}")))$effsize
}

gtTable <- mtcars %>% 
  select(hp, vs, am) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = vs) %>% 
  add_p() %>% 
  add_stat(fns = all_continuous() ~ my_ES_test) %>% 
  modify_header(add_stat_1 ~ "Effect size")
print(gtTable)

contTable <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am)
chisq.test(contTable, correct = FALSE)
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  contTable
#> X-squared = 0.90688, df = 1, p-value = 0.3409
cramer_v(contTable)
#> [1] 0.1042136
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an example including Cramer's V in the output table. Happy Programming!

```r
library(gtsummary)

my_ES_test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  rstatix::cohens_d(data, as.formula(glue::glue("{variable} ~ {by}")))$effsize
}
my_cramer_v <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  table(data[[variable]], data[[by]]) %>%
    rstatix::cramer_v()
}

gtTable <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  select(hp, vs, am) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = vs) %>% 
  add_p() %>% 
  add_stat(
    fns = list(all_continuous() ~ my_ES_test,
               all_categorical() ~ my_cramer_v)) %>% 
  modify_header(add_stat_1 ~ "**Effect size**")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

FYI, there is built-in support for Cohen's D so you don't need to create a custom method. You can see a complete list here https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html