# Effect size estimates for tbl_svysummary

Tags: gtsummary

I had a quick question. Is there any way to add effect size estimates (i.e., Cohen's D and/or Cramer's V) for tbl_svysummary when comparing demographic factors to one another? I am looking for pretty much the same answer that was provided for this post ([How to add the Chi-square effect size Cramer's V in the summary table using R package “gtsummary”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088568/how-to-add-the-chi-square-effect-size-cramers-v-in-the-summary-table-using-r-pa))

```
library(gtsummary)

my_ES_test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
rstatix::cohens_d(data, as.formula(glue::glue("{variable} ~ 
{by}")))$effsize
}
my_cramer_v <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  table(data[[variable]], data[[by]]) %>%
  rstatix::cramer_v()
 }

gtTable <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  select(hp, vs, am) %>% 
tbl_summary(by = vs) %>% 
add_p() %>% 
add_stat(
fns = list(all_continuous() ~ my_ES_test,
           all_categorical() ~ my_cramer_v)) %>% 
 modify_header(add_stat_1 ~ "**Effect size**")
```

however, when I tried the methodology suggested therein, it did not work for tbl_svysummary. Example below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(gtsummary)
my_ES_test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
rstatix::cohens_d(data, as.formula(glue::glue("{variable} ~ 
{by}")))$effsize
  }
my_cramer_v <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  table(data[[variable]], data[[by]]) %>%
  rstatix::cramer_v()
 }

tbl_svysummary_ex1 <- 
 survey::svydesign(~1, data = as.data.frame(Titanic), weights = 
~Freq) %>% 
  tbl_svysummary(by = Survived, percent = "row", include = 
c(Class, Age)) %>% 
  add_p(test = list(all_categorical() ~ "svy.chisq.test")) %>% 
  add_stat(
   fns = list(all_continuous() ~ my_ES_test,
           all_categorical() ~ my_cramer_v)) %>% 
  modify_header(add_stat_1 ~ "**Effect size**")
```

Furthermore, on the gtsummary website, there do not seem to be any instructions for how to do this in tbl_svysummary either. Any guidance here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Furthermore, is it possible to add the degrees of freedom and the raw chi-squared statistic as well? Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for code to calculate these quantitates, or asking how to incorporate these results into the gtsummary table? If the latter, please update your post with code+data that we can use to calculate the quantities. You can write custom methods to `add_p()` for svy data. Instructions are here: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html#custom-functions-1

Comment: tbl_svysummary_ex1 <-
  survey::svydesign(~1, data = as.data.frame(Titanic), weights = ~Freq) %>%
    tbl_svysummary(by = Survived, percent = "row", include = c(Class, Age)) %>%
  add_p(test = list(all_categorical() ~ "svy.chisq.test"))

Comment: I am asking how to incorporate these into the gtsummary table! I am wondering how to add an effect size in another column than includes a Cohen's D and/or Cramer's V to summarize the differences between "Class" and "Age" categories when they are stratified by "Survived" per the code above. Would be great to be able to include the degrees of freedom and the raw chi-squared statistic as well. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The examples below shoe the statistic and the DFs. If you want an effect size that is not returned by default, then you'll need to write a custom method for add_difference() that includes the estimate.

```r
library(gtsummary)

# create summary table
tbl_svysummary_ex1 <- 
  survey::svydesign(~1, data = as.data.frame(Titanic), weights = ~Freq) %>% 
  tbl_svysummary(by = Survived, percent = "row", include = c(Class, Age)) %>% 
  add_p(test = list(all_categorical() ~ "svy.chisq.test"))


tbl_svysummary_ex1$table_body |> names()
#>  [1] "variable"    "test_name"   "var_type"    "var_label"   "row_type"   
#>  [6] "label"       "stat_1"      "stat_2"      "test_result" "statistic"  
#> [11] "p.value"     "ndf"         "ddf"

# unhide the statistic and DF columns by assigning a header
tbl_svysummary_ex1 |> 
  modify_header(
    statistic = "**Chi-square**",
    ndf = "**ndf**",
    ddf = "**ddf**"
  ) |> 
  modify_fmt_fun(c(statistic, ndf, ddf) ~ style_sigfig) |> 
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **No**, N = 1,490 | **Yes**, N = 711 | **Chi-square** | **p-value** | **ndf** | **ddf** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class |  |  | 0.41 | 0.7 | 2.6 | 81 |
| 1st | 122 (38%) | 203 (62%) |  |  |  |  |
| 2nd | 167 (59%) | 118 (41%) |  |  |  |  |
| 3rd | 528 (75%) | 178 (25%) |  |  |  |  |
| Crew | 673 (76%) | 212 (24%) |  |  |  |  |
| Age |  |  | 0.63 | 0.4 | 1.0 | 31 |
| Child | 52 (48%) | 57 (52%) |  |  |  |  |
| Adult | 1,438 (69%) | 654 (31%) |  |  |  |  |

<sup>Created on 2022-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much! However, I am wondering if there is any more guidance around what the function itself would be for tbl_svysummary? I looked at the directions on your website (https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html#custom-functions-1) but they were not clear to me. Furthermore, I tried the custom function from another post addressing this topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088568/how-to-add-the-chi-square-effect-size-cramers-v-in-the-summary-table-using-r-pa), but it does not work for tbl_svysummary. Any additional guidance would be appreciated here, thanks!

Comment: I previously requested you update your post with code to calculate the stats you wanted to include. If you do that, include your attempt to write the custom method that is outlined in the link, then someone could perhaps help you get everything you're after

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks so much for this answer and my apologies for not following your instructions fully in your first post. I have updated the original post accordingly to demonstrate the issue. Any support you or someone else can provide would be so appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello! Just following up on this posting, thank you :)!

Comment: I dont think the code you posted for effect sizes works with survey design objects? please confirm.

Comment: Hi Daniel! This is correct -- the code I posted for effect sizes does not work for survey objects. However, that is the reason I made this post, as I do not see any options in gtsummary to estimate effect sizes for chi squared tests of survey objects. The above code is the closest I have found to answering this question, however it does not work for survey objects. I would love to know if there is any way at all to generate effect sizes for chi squared tests of survey objects in gtsummary, or any code that could be adapted to include these values in a gtsummary table! Thank you :)

Comment: I think we had a miscommunication. I tried asking in the beginning if your question was _how_ to generate these statistics vs how to place custom stats in a gtsummary table. I can't help with the first in this case. Once you figure that out, if you continue having issues putting them in a gtsummary table, i can help.